# How do I retrieve particular value from an ArrayList<String> in Spring

Tags: java, spring, list, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

The client program should display the details of all players and their corresponding country details.  If given a country name, it should also display all the player names who belong to that country. Two players belong to one country and the other 3 players belong to another country.

> I have declared 4 list's in my **beans.xml** file in Spring. I want to
> know how can I give retrieve particular list value?

**My beans.xml file:**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
<bean id="player" class="com.my.bean.SpringIOC5">
    <property name="playerId">
    <list>
    <value>p1</value>
    <value>p2</value>
    <value>p3</value>
    <value>p4</value>
    <value>p5</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="playerName">
    <list >
    <value>pn1</value>
    <value>pn2</value>
    <value>pn3</value>
    <value>pn4</value>
    <value>pn5</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="country" ref="cnty"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="cnty" class="com.my.bean.Country">
    <property name="countryId">
    <list>
    <value>c1</value>
    <value>c2</value>
    <value>c3</value>
    <value>c4</value>
    <value>c5</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="countryName">
    <list>
    <value>cn1</value>
    <value>cn2</value>
    <value>cn3</value>
    <value>cn4</value>
    <value>cn5</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

**My Player class:**

```
    public class SpringIOC5 {
    //public class Player
private List<String> playerId;
private List<String> playerName;
private Country country;
public SpringIOC5() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public SpringIOC5(List<String> playerId, List<String> playerName, Country country) {
    super();
    this.playerId = playerId;
    this.playerName = playerName;
    this.country = country;
}
public List<String> getPlayerId() {
    return playerId;
}
public void setPlayerId(List<String> playerId) {
    this.playerId = playerId;
}
public List<String> getPlayerName() {
    return playerName;
}
public void setPlayerName(List<String> playerName) {
    this.playerName = playerName;
}
public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SpringIOC5 [playerId=" + playerId + ", playerName=" + playerName + ", country=" + country + "]";
}

}
```

**My Country class:**

```
    public class Country {
private List<String> countryId;
private List<String> countryName;
public Country() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Country(List<String> countryId, List<String> countryName) {
    super();
    this.countryId = countryId;
    this.countryName = countryName;
}
public List<String> getCountryId() {
    return countryId;
}
public void setCountryId(List<String> countryId) {
    this.countryId = countryId;
}
public List<String> getCountryName() {
    return countryName;
}
public void setCountryName(List<String> countryName) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Country [countryId=" + countryId + ", countryName=" + countryName + "]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods of ArrayList class to fetch the specific values.

```
countryId.get(indexNo.);
```

check more methods in oracle java docs here

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html